# Display Variant Images in collection page, Shopify Dawn Theme

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to display Variant Images on Collection page but images are not displaying
Here is my code:

```
{% if request.page_type == 'collection' %}
  {% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
    <div class="variant-images-row">
      {% for variant in product.variants %}
        <div class="variant-image">
          {% if variant.available %}
            <form action="/cart/add" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ variant.id }}" />
              <button type="submit" class="variant-button">
                <img src="{{ variant.image.src | asset_url }}" alt="{{ variant.title }}" width="100" height="100">
              </button>
            </form>
          {% else %}
            <p>{{ variant.title }} - Sold Out</p>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% if product.has_only_default_variant %}
  <form method="post" action="/cart/add">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />
    <button type="submit" class "variant-button">
      <img src="{{ product.variants.first.image.src | asset_url }}" alt="{{ product.variants.first.title }}" width="100" height="100">
    </button>
  </form>
{% endif %}
```

I have set the variation images to the product but can't able to fetch the product variant image